# Barometer vs Rangefinder

Tags: barometer, rangefinder

On a small 6-7inch drone do I need a barometer, rangefinder or both? Is there a standard practice or does it just depend on use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you don't need a rangefinder or a barometer for a normal drone but if you want to make a drone with altitude hold, **I would recommend a barometer** over a rangefinder because a rangefinder will not work very high up or when you are flying over certain surfaces like water. A rangefinder would only be good if you stay close to the ground and don't fly over reflective surfaces.

Comment: Thanks. I hike up to a mountain and then fly the drone would that cause the barometer to give false information?

Comment: As long as you turn the drone on at the top of the mountain, it should register that air pressure as ground level. So there should be no problem.